# Why my <form> getting the attribute "novalidate"?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-validate

My `<form>` is getting the attribute `novalidate` and this is making him not be validated by jQuery.Validate. I'm using version 1.9 and 1.11, and both generate this errors.

i'm not using HTM5 validation ...

my page code:

SCRIPT:

```
<!-- JQUERY VALIDATION -->
    <script src="js/jquery.validate.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#enviando").hide();
                $("#form").validate({
                    rules: {  
                        nome: { required: true, minlength: 2 }, 
                        empresa: { required: true },
                        email: { required: true, email: true },             
                        telefone: { required: true },
                        assunto: { required: true },
                        mensagem: { required: true }
                    },  
                    messages: {  
                        nome: { required: 'Preencha o campo nome', minlength: 'No mínimo 2 letras' }, 
                        empresa: { required: 'Preencha o campo Empresa' },
                        email: { required: 'Informe o seu Email', email: 'Informe um Email válido' },               
                        telefone: { required: 'Informe seu Telefone' },
                        assunto: { required: 'Preencha o campo com o Assunto' },
                        mensagem: { required: 'Escreva sua Mensagem' }

                    },  
                    submitHandler: function( form ){
                        $("#form").hide();
                        $("#enviando").show();              
                        var dados = $( form ).serialize();  
                        $.ajax({  
                            type: "POST",  
                            url: "envia_contato.asp",
                            data: dados,  
                            success: function( data )  
                            {  
                                alert("teste");

                            }  
                        });  

                        return false;  
                    }           
                });

                $("#form").removeAttr("novalidate");

            //Input and Textarea Click-Clear
            $('input[type=text]').focus(function() {
                if($(this).attr('readonly') || $(this).attr('readonly') == 'readonly') return false;
                if ($(this).val() === $(this).attr('title')) {
                        $(this).val('');
                }   
                }).blur(function() {
                if($(this).attr('readonly') || $(this).attr('readonly') == 'readonly') return false;
                if ($(this).val().length === 0) {
                    $(this).val($(this).attr('title'));
                }                        
            }); 
            $('textarea').focus(function() {
                if ($(this).text() === $(this).attr('title')) {
                        $(this).text('');
                    }        
                }).blur(function() {
                if ($(this).text().length === 0) {
                    $(this).text($(this).attr('title'));
                }                        
            }); 



            });

        </script>
```

FORM Markup:

```
<div class="form_faleconosco">
                <div id="enviando"><br/><img src="imagens/ajax-loader.gif"><br/><span>ENVIANDO FORMULÁRIO</span></div>

                <form action="" id="form" class="feedback_form"  method="post">
                    <label class="label-name"></label>
                    <input class="field-name form_field" type="text" title="Name" value="Name" name="nome" style="width: 400px;"/>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <label class="label-empresa"></label>
                    <input class="field-empresa form_field" type="text" title="Empresa" value="Empresa" name="empresa" style="width: 400px;"/>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <label class="label-email"></label>
                    <input class="field-email form_field" type="text" title="Email" value="Email" name="email" style="width: 400px;"/>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <label class="label-phone"></label>
                    <input class="field-phone form_field" type="text" title="Telefone" value="Telefone" name="telefone" style="width: 400px;"/>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <label class="label-subject"></label>
                    <input class="field-subject form_field" type="text" title="Assunto" value="Assunto" name="assunto" style="width: 400px;"/>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <label class="label-message"></label>
                    <textarea class="field-message form_field" title="Mensagem" rows="5" cols="45" name="mensagem" style="width: 400px;">Mensagem</textarea>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <input id="submit2" class="feedback_go" type="button" value="Enviar Mensagem" name="submit"/>
                </form>

            </div>
```

LIVE VERSION: http://www.alsite.com.br/prime/faleconosco.html

Comment: Can you try to get your code down to *just enough* necessary to demonstrate the problem by removing irrelevant lines?

Comment: sure... i put that to confirm that i'm not using html5 validation

Comment: How does your `<!doctype>`-declaration look like?

Comment: like this:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

Comment: The `novalidate` attribute is being added by the jQuery Validate plugin itself (in order to disable HTML5 validation just in case) - this is not a source of your issue. Most probably there is an exception in jQuery Validate internals (try checking console for that). It often happens that jQuery Validate doesn't play well with jQuery 1.9, for starters you should try reverting to jQuery 1.83 (of course if your project allows that).

Comment: i'm using jQuery 1.8.2... see my live link, and on console i'm getting any errors...

Comment: Well I just went to your live link and the validation works correctly for me there (there are some issues with displaying the messages, they are squished into some incredibly small boxes and hard to read but it works).

Comment: oO, sure? How i can see that? I'm not finding this...

Comment: I can email you a screenshot if you want.

Comment: @tpeczek my email is on my Profile page

Comment: I have played a little bit more and figured out something, please check the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so I have played a little bit with your page and I think I know where the true issue is: **default values**. You are setting default values for your fields and jQuery validate is treating them as values (it has no way to know different). This is why it sometimes works, sometimes not (I was able make the validation messages appear while switching focus in non standard way).

I would suggest a way around this by adding custom validation method:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    ...
    $.validator.addMethod("defaultTitle", function(value, element) {
        return !($(element).val() === $(element).attr('title'));
    }, $.validator.messages.required);

    $("#form").validate({
        rules: {  
            nome: { required: true, defaultTitle: true, minlength: 2 }, 
            ...
        },  
        messages: {  
            nome: { required: 'Preencha o campo nome', defaultTitle: 'Preencha o campo nome', minlength: 'No mínimo 2 letras' }, 
            ...
        },  
        submitHandler: function( form ){
            ...
        }           
    });
    ...
});
```

You should apply this new `defaultTitle` rule to the fields for which you are setting default values (and you don't need to remove the `novalidate` attribute).

Another reason why the jQuery Validation plugin doesn't fire up is that you have used `button` instead of `submit`:

`<input type="button" />` buttons will not submit a form - they don't do anything by default. They're generally used in conjunction with JavaScript as part of an AJAX application.

`<input type="submit">` buttons will submit the form they are in when the user clicks on them, unless you specify otherwise with JavaScript.

jQuery Validation is hooking up to standard submit event, you should change your markup like this:

```
<div class="form_faleconosco">
    ...
    <form action="" id="form" class="feedback_form"  method="post">
        ...
        <input id="submit2" class="feedback_go" type="submit" value="Enviar Mensagem" name="submit"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: so my `input`code now shows like this right? `<input class="field-name form_field" type="text" title="Name" value="Name" name="nome" style="width: 400px;" defaultTitle/>`

Comment: @Preston you don't need to apply it through the markup, you can do it like the other rules (see the rules for `nome` in above code).

Comment: ah.. ok.. i will try.. and about the error messages, you tell me that apears on smallest boxes.. this will fix that?

Comment: @Preston Nope, you will most probably need to restyle the error message element or take a look at `errorPlacement` option.

Comment: i update my live link with your codes, and i'm getting the same novalidate attribute... if i leave the Default Value empty, this don't work too....

Comment: @Preston Once again: the `novalidate` attribute should be there, it is added by the jQuery Validation plugin for a reason and it is not an issue. I will look through your online form to check what is going on in there.

Comment: @Preston I have found another issue in your form and I have updated the answer. Please change that and keep in mind that this might not be the end of the issues as I'm unable to check what is happening further in the pipeline

Comment: Very nice!!! Now, with some implements i have suppressed the errors and add a red border to my input fields. Thanks a lot!!